# Switch для string

Tags: c++

Задача: юзер вводит команды, программа их выполняет. Хотел использовать **switch**, но он не хочет обрабатывать переменную типа **string**, только **int**.

Вот часть кода:

```
while (command == "NULL")
{
    cout << '>';
    cin >> command;
}

if (command == "exit")
{
    exit = 1;
}

if (command == "map")
{
    view_map (map, POLE);
}

if (command == "goto")
{
    string direction;
    int steps;
    cin >> direction >> steps;
    if (steps < 0)
        cout << "И каk ета па твоиму?" << endl;

    if (direction == "left")
        HeroCoord_x = HeroCoord_x - steps;

    if (direction == "right")
        HeroCoord_x = HeroCoord_x + steps;

    if (direction == "up")
        HeroCoord_y = HeroCoord_y - steps;

    if (direction == "down")
        HeroCoord_y = HeroCoord_y + steps;

    if ((HeroCoord_x < 0) || (HeroCoord_x > POLE) || (HeroCoord_y < 0) || (HeroCoord_y > POLE))
    {
        cout << "Нипалушайтсанах!" << endl;
        if (direction == "left")
            HeroCoord_x = HeroCoord_x + steps;

        if (direction == "right")
            HeroCoord_x = HeroCoord_x - steps;

        if (direction == "up")
            HeroCoord_y = HeroCoord_y + steps;

        if (direction == "down")
            HeroCoord_y = HeroCoord_y - steps;
    }
    else
    {
        make_map (map, POLE);
        go_to (map, HeroCoord_x, HeroCoord_y);
    }
}
```

Как реализовать это проще?

Comment: Не просто int, а const int. Значения используемые в свиче не могут вычисляться "на ходу".<br />
А вместо HeroCoord_* можно использовать что-то вроде
<pre><code>
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
}Coord;
...
Coord heroCoord;
...
heroCoord.x + 5;
...</code></pre>
В если герой не один в вашем мире, то эту структуру можно применить к другим персонажам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать маппинг handler-ов и использовать его.
Что-то вроде:

```
struct Handler {
    void handle() = 0;
    virtual ~Handler() {}
};

struct ExitHandler : public Handler {
    void handle() {
        //code here
    }
};

struct MapHandler  : public Handler {
    void handle() {
        //code here
    }
};

struct GotoHandler  : public Handler {
    void handle() {
        //code here
    }
};

//====================

std::map<std::string, Handler*> handlers;
handlers["exit"] = new ExitHandler();
handlers["goto"] = new GotoHandler();
handlers["map"] = new MapHandler();

//-----------------------

while (command == "NULL")
{
    cout << '>';
    cin >> command;
}
handlers[command]->handle();
```

Это конечно черновая и небезопасная реализация, но смысл я думаю понятен.

Answer (score 13):

Можно использовать отображение строк в числа:

```
std::map <std::string, int> mapping;

mapping["left"]  = LEFT;
mapping["up"]    = UP;
mapping["right"] = RIGHT;
mapping["down"]  = DOWN;

switch (mapping[command]) {
    case LEFT:  doLeft();  break;
    case UP:    doUp();    break;
    case RIGHT: doRight(); break;
    case DOWN:  doDown();  break;
}
```

где LEFT, UP, RIGHT, DOWN - произвольные числа.

Answer (score 6):

Если не опасаться коллизий, то можно использовать `constexpr` функции из С++11, и делать `switch` по хешам строк.

```
// FNV-1a hash, 32-bit 
inline constexpr std::uint32_t fnv1a(const char* str, std::uint32_t hash = 2166136261UL) {
    return *str ? fnv1a(str + 1, (hash ^ *str) * 16777619ULL) : hash;
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "bb";

    switch (fnv1a(s.c_str())) {
    case fnv1a("a"): std::cout << "A\n"; break;
    case fnv1a("bb"): std::cout << "B\n"; break;
    case fnv1a("ccc"): std::cout << "C\n"; break;
    };    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. command == "map" - и это работает? Интересно знать, как. Вы сравниваете указатели, а нужно сравнивать строки, для этого есть функция strcmp (или может оператор == перегружен для char* по умолчанию? я что-то не в теме :)
2. Когда я решал подобную проблему, я просто написал функцию, а строки положил в массив:

   ```
   const char* protoCommands[]= {
                 "AUTH",
                 "REG",
                 "ADDPT",
                 "ACCPT",
                 "GETPTS",
                 "GETSTATE",
                 "DISC"
               };
               const int protoSize=sizeof(protoCommands)/sizeof(char*);
               /* ... */
           int switchFunc(char* buf)
           {   
            for(int i=0;i<protoSize;++i)
             if (!strcmp(buf,protoCommands[i]))
              return i;
            return -1;
           }
           /* ... */
           switch(switchFunc(buf))
           {
              ...
           }
   ```

Comment: Последовательный поиск. Время O(n). map должен побыстрее работать

Comment: Вы не правы: command: std::string. Для std::string определены операторы сравнения когда слева или справа const char*.

Comment: @alexlz за log(n) будет: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/